# how can i create dynamically flowlayoutpanels and tabpages in my form

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, flowlayoutpanel

I need to create some *tabpages* and *flowlayoutpanels* in each tab-pages dynamically in my form loaded. After that i wanna add some button in each *flowlayoutpanel*.

**here is my code:**

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim tabcntrl As New TabControl
    Dim flp(4) As FlowLayoutPanel
    Dim btn As New Button
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tabcntrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        tabcntrl.Alignment = TabAlignment.Left
        Me.Controls.Add(tabcntrl)
        For i = 1 To 5
            tabcntrl.TabPages.Add("TAB" & i - 1)
            flp(i - 1).Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            tabcntrl.TabPages(i - 1).Controls.Add(flp(i - 1))
        Next
        button_adding()
    End Sub
    Private Sub button_adding()
        For i = 1 To 5
            For j = 1 To i
                btn.Text = j
                btn.Size = New Size(75, 75)
                btn.Visible = True
                flp(i - 1).Controls.Add(btn)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
  End Class
```

Comment: *"I want to do X, here's my code"* isn't a question.  You have to explain your specific problem, i.e. what's happening that shouldn't or not happening that should.

Comment: That said, I suggest that you tackle this a different way.  Start by defining a user control that contains your `FlowLayoutPanel` and you `Buttons`.  Next, define a class that inherits `TabPage` and adds an instance of that user control to itself upon creation.  Now, in your application, all you have to do is create an instance of that custom `TabPage` class and your `FlowLayoutPanel` and `Buttons` are already there.

Comment: "Dim flp(4) As FlowLayoutPanel" is my problem it is not working getting "System.NullReferenceException" error. i cant specify flowlayoutpanels in each tabpages. i have to create flowlayoutpanels and tabpages dynamically

Comment: `For i = 1 To 5` In this loop every time you use i you subtract one form it. Why not just use a loop like `For i = 0 To 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before setting the `Dock` property of the `FlowLayoutPanel`, you need to instantiate a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

```
...
tabcntrl.TabPages.Add("TAB" & i - 1)
flp(i - 1) = New FlowLayoutPanel    ' <== ADD THIS LINE
flp(i - 1).Dock = DockStyle.Fill
...
```